# Subclassing DateTimeField in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm trying to subclass the `DateTimeField` in Django and i'm having some strange occurrences.

I'm trying to override the `to_python` method. However, when the value is attained from the database, it goes to the method: `get_prep_value`, The method looks like below:

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
    value = self.to_python(value) ### THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
    if value is not None and settings.USE_TZ and timezone.is_naive(value):
        # For backwards compatibility, interpret naive datetimes in local
        # time. This won't work during DST change, but we can't do much
        # about it, so we let the exceptions percolate up the call stack.
        try:
            name = '%s.%s' % (self.model.__name__, self.name)
        except AttributeError:
            name = '(unbound)'
        warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
                      " while time zone support is active." %
                      (name, value),
                      RuntimeWarning)
        default_timezone = timezone.get_default_timezone()
        value = timezone.make_aware(value, default_timezone)
    return value
```

The second line it's calling the `to_python` method and does NOT call my overridden method. Is there a way to force it to call my method without overriding `get_prep_value` as well? Why is it that my over ridden method is not being called and the base class method is being called instead?

**EDIT**

here is my class

```
class MyField(DateTimeField):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        import pytz
        default_timezone = pytz.timezone("UTC")
        if value and timezone.is_naive(value):
            value = timezone.make_aware(value, default_timezone)
        return strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', value.timetuple())

    def to_python(self, value):
        # MY IMPLEMENTATION
```

Comment: Could you paste more code, your field class and a form class?

Comment: I put the relevant parts of the code there.

Comment: Are you sure that type of this object is `MyField`? You should not need to override `get_prep_value()`.

Comment: Whats happening is that its going to `get_prep_value` in the `DateField` class. Which is calling `self.to_python` and going to the `DateTimeField` class.